# Cartoon about a skeleton that takes people's brain power

Tags: story-identification, cartoon

Tere’s this cartoon I saw once, years ago, but I remember it pretty well. I saw this cartoon in early 2000s no later than 2007

It was about these two kids, a scientist and this really big strong guy. They woke up some sacred skeleton-being and it steals their brain power, or “cheese”.

This skeleton creature can only find them if they breathe because it smells their breath to locate them. If the skeleton takes their brain power, the scientist can have someone temporarily provide some else’s brain power to keep them from turning into the skeleton's minion. This works fine until the scientist gets his brain power taken and the other characters freeze him with some magic words until they figure out how to destroy the skeleton. They find how to do this by putting something in the skeleton's left sock and when thrown in some ancient river or lake it resets everyone’s brain power to normal.

Comment: When actually did you read this? ("Years ago" needs to be a bit more specific).

Comment: It is a very evocative description.

Comment: I’m pretty sure I saw it between 2003 to 2008

Comment: Also I’m pretty sure the girl has black hair and when she woke the skeleton up she slammed the coffin lid back down and put a ladder on top of it to prevent the skeleton from leaving but it didn’t work

Answer (score 3):

There's only one kid in it but this is definitely *Jackie Chan Adventures*.

Episode:  ["Chi of the Vampire"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0613922/plotsummary?ref_=tt_ov_pl)

Synopsis from [the wiki](https://jackiechanadventures.fandom.com/wiki/Jiangshi):

> In an abandoned castle where Uncle was acquiring rare antiques, **Jade accidentally awakens the Jiangshi, which sucks out Tohru's, Jade's, and Uncle's chi**. In a chi transfusion (similar to a blood transfusion, but different), Tohru gets a part of Jade's and Jade a part of Uncle's, making the recipient behave much like the donor. **But when Uncle himself is affected, no one knows how to effect the magic for the transfer**, and so Uncle becomes a vampire slave.
>
> The only way to reclaim the chi is to **find a toadstool in a graveyard, place it in the vampire's left sock**, and throw it into a river before sunrise; otherwise, the chi will remain lost forever. The Jiangshi sets out to stop the Chans as soon as it learns of their intentions, but loses its socks and the chi it stole. As the sun rises, the Jiangshi is blasted into dust.

Comment: It's iffy quality, but https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Za0br3hia4U is a short enough clip that it probably won't get yanked.